# Get GUID By TermName - jsom

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-online

I need to pass a term name as a parameter and return the GUID of that particular term in SharePoint 2013, JSOM

As an example if I pass "My Term 1" it should return the corresponding GUID of "My Term 1".

[image]

```js
var termGuid=getTermByName('My Term 1');

function getTermByName(TermName){
  return term.get_id();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SP.Taxonomy.TermStore.getTerms Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269620.aspx) could be utilized for finding [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) in [TermStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn269589.aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to find a [Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) by Label using JSOM:

```
function findTermsByLabel(label,success,error)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var ts = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
     var matchInfo = new SP.Taxonomy.LabelMatchInformation(ctx);
     matchInfo.set_termLabel(label);
     matchInfo.set_trimUnavailable(true);
     var termMatches = ts.getTerms(matchInfo);
     ctx.load(termMatches);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
           var terms = termMatches.get_data();
           success(terms);
        },
        error);    
}
```

Usage

```
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.ClientContext', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.js'));
SP.SOD.registerSod('SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['SP.ClientContext', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession'], function(){

   var termLabel = '--term label goes here--';

   findTermsByLabel(termLabel,
     function(terms){
        if(terms.length == 0)
            console.log('Term has not been found');
        else if(terms.length > 1)    
            console.log(String.format("Several Terms exist with '{0}' label",termLabel));
        else {
            console.log(String.format('Term has been found: {0}'),terms[0].get_id().toString());     
        }    
     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
     });

});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it always gives 'Term has not been found' .. not sure the reason yet.. (I've given existing term name correctly)